# How to get browser extension popup to display a variable

Tags: javascript, firefox, popup, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating my first Firefox extension. 
The idea is simple:

1. Find all lists on page.
2. Put a border around them.
3. Record the number of lists to a variable.
4. Display this variable in the popup.

I can't figure out #4, displaying the variable in the popup. Please help a beginner!

Here is my code:

```
// Variables
const $ulList = document.querySelectorAll('ul')
const $olList = document.querySelectorAll('ol')
const $dlList = document.querySelectorAll('dl')

// Finds all list elements
function findLists($ulList, $olList, $dlList) {
    // Gives them a pink border
    for (const $ul of $ulList) {
        $ul.style.border = "5px solid pink";
    }
    for (const $ol of $olList) {
        $ol.style.border = "5px solid pink";
    }
    for (const $dl of $dlList) {
        $dl.style.border = "5px solid hotpink";
    }
}

// Records length of all lists
var $ulListLength = $ulList.length
console.log('ul Lists: ' + $ulListLength)
var $olListLength = $olList.length
console.log('ol Lists: ' + $olListLength)
var $dlListLength = $dlList.length
console.log('dl Lists: ' + $dlListLength)

// The total number of lists on the page
$totalListsLength = $ulListLength + $olListLength + $dlListLength
console.log('Total lists: ' + $totalListsLength)
```

Here is the manifest.json. Please note that `pop-display.js` is currently empty.

```
{
  "description": "QA common style mistakes for Canada.ca style guide.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "WebPubQA",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/sinc0115/web-pub-qa",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon/outline_highlight_black_48dp.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["webPubQA.js", "pop-display.js"]
    }
  ],

   "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],

  "background": {
        "scripts": ["pop-display.js"]
    },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon/outline_highlight_black_48dp.png",
    "default_title": "Web Pub QA",
    "default_popup": "index-pop.html"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that it can be done.

Here is one which doesn't require "content_scripts" to function:

```
// in popup.js
const code = `
const ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
const ol = document.querySelectorAll('ol');
const dl = document.querySelectorAll('dl');

// add border to all
[...ul, ...ol, ...dl].forEach(item => item.style.border = '5px solid pink');

// Records length of all lists
const ulLen = ul.length;
const olLen = ol.length;
const dlLen = dl.length;
const total = ulLen + olLen + dlLen;

console.log('ul Lists: ' + ulLen);
console.log('ol Lists: ' + olLen);
console.log('dl Lists: ' + dlLen);
console.log('Total lists: ' + total);

// return value is passed back to the tabs.executeScript
return total; 
`;

// tabs.executeScript without tabId inject into active tab
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code}, result => {
  // result is array, the value passed is result[0]
  // do whatever with result[0]
});
```

Another method is:

- add a content script
- have a `runtime.onMessage.addListener()` in content script
- send a `tabs.sendMessage()` from pop up to count the LIST
- wait for a message back from content script to display total in pop-up